# Sails multiple handlers for the same route

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

As the title suggests, I would like to assign multiple action handlers within different controllers for the same route in Sails Js

What I have tried:

```
"post /rest/users": [{
    controller: "FirstController",
    action: "someAction"
},
{
    controller: "SecondController",
    action: "otherAction"
}]
```

But this gives me error 51 in Sails, and neither action is reached (when debugged). I searched for this solution but I couldn't find something.

I know that Sails uses Express's route middleware and I found that this can be done in Express with the following route:

```
app.post('/users', createUser, saveToDB, endTheResponse, sendEmail);
```

I know some possible workarounds (like requiring the controller within the first one) but that's not what I'm looking for, and I couldn't adapt the Express example route to Sails one.

Any suggestions are welcomed! Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, after searching for over than 1 week, I found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/5737561). So everyone who's dealing with this and have problems calling multiple controllers here's how this can be achieved. From the gist:

> *Routes can now specify a list of targets, which will be run in order
>   (this allows for binding chains of middleware directly to routes).
>   Both controllers (controller.action) and arbitrary middleare
>   (middleware) functions from the new, optional middleware directory can
>   be specified, in any order:*

```
{
    'post /signup': ['user.unique', 'user.create', 'verifyemail.send'],
    '/auth/logout': ['authenticated', 'auth.logout']
}
```

> *You can also still use classic `{controller: 'foo', action: 'bar' }`
>   notation. And conveniently, miscellaneous strings are treated as
>   redirects:*

```
{
    // Alias '/logout' to '/auth/logout'
    'get /logout': '/auth/logout',
    '/thegoogle': 'http://google.com'
}
```