# How do i invoke different controller action using same URL Pattern in Sailsjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

How to use two different controllers for the same url?
 Ex:

```
 // config/routes.js
 module.exports.routes = {
  // The simple route you use to access to the search controller for now
  'get /search': 'SearchController.index',
  // Route the calls to different controller
  'get /:city/:locality': 'SearchController.index',
  'get /:city/:product_name': 'ProductController.index'
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the answer to this question will fit you

[Sails multiple handlers for the same route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025783/sails-multiple-handlers-for-the-same-route)